# Let $H$ and $K$ be normal subgroups of $G$ such that $H \cap K = \langle e \rangle$ and $HK = G$. Prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $H \times K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I can't figure out how to do this. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Use normality to show that the element $hkh^{-1}k^{-1} = e$ for any $h\in H$, and $k\in K$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can build the isomorphism $\varphi: H \times K \to G$ explicitly:
$$
\varphi\left((h, k)\right) = h \cdot k \quad \text{for all}\ h \in H,\ k \in K.
$$
Then you just need to check that $\varphi$ is indeed 1-to-1, onto, and a group homomorphism.

Comment: Does the 1st isomorphism theorem then come into play?

Comment: @grayQuant no, it's not necessary here. When it's established that $\varphi$ is bijective and a homomorphism, then $\varphi$ is an isomorphism simply by definition.